# lost data after restart the influxdb?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

I wrote a script to fetch some data from influxdb.It works well,but some day this script report an error:

`requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)'), IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)`

and then,I restart the influxdb by *service influxdb restart*
but after restart,I can not query the data of past 4 weeks for all databases.
So how should I restore those data?

Comment: Is the Influx service running via a Docker container without a data volume mounted? That's the only thing that I can think of that would not persist the data

Comment: @cricket_007 no,I install influxdb by `yum local install`,the version of influxdb is 1.31. I thought the data file still in disk,just something wrong with the wal file